# How to check which web service am I using?

Tags: windows

I want to check  which web service i am using.I am using window 10

I tried google more but did not get any thing.

So please kindly provide me the best way to find out that which web service 
am i using?

Comment: No context, completely unclear what your asking.

Comment: I want how to check that what web services am i using on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer does not just connect to one "web service".

The Windows **Task Manager** can tell you about the *amount* of communications occurring.

The included Windows **Resource Monitor** application, in the **Network** tab, can tell you something about network connections as they are made and used.

The Windows Base Filtering Engine can be set to log all communications in the Security Event Log, but that log gets deep in a hurry.

Some 3rd party firewall packages (e.g., Sphinx) offer an ability to conveniently list and summarize connections as they are attempted.  And of course firewall software can give you the ability to disallow some/all communications.

Some 3rd party diagnostics/monitoring tools, such as Wireshark and Fiddler 2, can give you details about the contents of specific communications.

A locally implemented DNS server could provide a log of name resolutions requested.  That's getting pretty geeky, but it does actually provide some good insights to watch such a log to get to know what normally, *and abnormally*, happens.  The configuration of such a server can also serve to provide a possible way of blocking some communications before they ever get started.

In short, **a modern cloud-integrated Windows system does a LOT of communications normally**.  Without in-depth understanding of both Windows and Networking I suspect any of the above-listed displays could be overwhelming.  As you can see, the answer isn't simple.

Most likely the first and most complete answer to your question is that your computer is connecting to "lots and lots of web services all over the world under many different conditions".

The next question to ask is:

**Why do you want the information and what are you hoping to do with it?**

Narrowing the question down can yield better answers.